# Correct way to load config into Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

I need to read config.json file before my application will start.
This config contains urls to my back-end services. Which will be used into redux action-creators.

I have 2 approaches:

1. fetch json and save data into state. And than get urls from state
   into action creators which is **anti-pattern**
2. fetch json and define
       data as global variable. Than i can access global variables from my
       action-creator.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider the following solution:

- Fetch the data from your configuration file and save its result at runtime in a module (singletone) called config.js
- Import config.js in your application (most probably in your api module where you delegate fetch operations with the server).

IMO the main advantage of this approach is that you do not pollute the the global namespace and you keep things clean using a separate module.
This approach could work best for static or dynamic configurations.

To be honest do not sure if your store is the right place to keep configuration as AFAIK it was designed for maintaining the state tree of your application so could be considered the right place in case your configurations are in some how dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I will choose approach 2 because it's **config** not *state* of your app. It won't change during runtime.

But I'm not sure what your app looks like, if your config does change dynamically then putting it in the redux store makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. i will fetch json file and define it as global variable

   fetch('config.json').then(data => window.CONFIG = data)
2. if config file contains some data which is relative to UI, you can set it to intialState in store

   const initalState = {
     config: window.CONFIG
   }